# Why is this question allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, site-policies

[Is Ragnarok Online enjoyable without using bots or cash items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3031/is-ragnarok-online-enjoyable-without-using-bots-or-cash-items)

The question is asking whether a game is enjoyable within a set of circumstances. Given the format of the website, this doesn't seem to be constructive or follow any of the question guidelines laid out in the faq. This seems unanswerable, given that enjoyability varies between people. I guess my understanding of the site formats is muddled. Questions dealing with plot points, regardless of quality are disallowed, but this is ok?

Comment: Questions about plot points are perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not.

It's from the very early days of the site, however, from before we really knew what was good and bad practice. It never really came back up until recent edits, and now should be closed and deleted.

Comment: Thanks. Some recent discussions regarding a plot question led me to this, and I'm trying to clarify what qualifies as appropriate questions.